# Using Index-Match in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Am trying to insert a Index-Match function in my VBA macro 
It looks like this:

Columns("C:C").Forumla = "=INDEX('[blabla.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$4:$F$102,MATCH(B1,'[blabla.xlsm]Sheet1'!$G$4:$G$102,0))"

However I keep getting "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Any tips, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies - should have added a bit more detail. I have a file with data, and I've inserted a column in between the 2 columns of data that the file comes with. I want to place the index-match formula in the newly created column, and then copy paste the index-match column and 1 out of the initial 2 columns into a different sheet. Hence the use of "column()".

Comment: `Forumla` isn't a member of the `Range` class. Does `Formula` work?

Comment: .formula works for a TEXT() function, but not for the Index() function that is referencing other sheets

Comment: I presume it's a different error though - 1004 by any chance? Try taking the formula into an actual cell - if Excel can't evaluate it, you can't have VBA code that attempts to force that invalid formula into a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `Range` variable, and assign it to `Columns("C:C")` e.g. `Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Columns("C:C")` (if that's in a standard module) or `Set myRange = Me.Columns("C:C")` (if that's in a worksheet module).

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Columns("C:C")
myRange.Formula = "..."
```

Then when you type the dot in `myRange.`, you'll get a dropdown listing the available members, parameter-quickinfo tooltips, and compile-time validation. The reason your code was allowed to compile and run (regardless of whether `Option Explicit` is specified or not) is because `Columns` returns a `Range` object, but doesn't have any parameters - the `("C:C")` arguments are in fact provided to the `Range.[_Default]` property, which returns a `Variant`. Any member calls chained to it, are therefore only resolved at run-time, i.e. any typo won't prevent compilation, and will throw error 438 at run-time.

By declaring a `Range` variable, you're "type-casting" that `Variant` into a `Range`, and from there the compiler is able to validate what members exist, and throw *compile-time* errors given a typo.

Comment: Legend. It worked. Cheers m8.

Comment: ( @Riyer - If this worked, and solves the issue for you, you can flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.  This gives extra credit to the author, and removes your question from the Unanswered queue.)